# What are code A and code S?

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology

I pretty often hear SC2 shoutcasters talking about *code A* and *code S*.  What is it, exactly ?  A league ?  Some sort or special ranking for grandmaster ranked players ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are tiers of the Global Starcraft League, held by [GomTV](http://www.gomtv.net) in Korea. Players who qualify for Code A (which is inferior to Code S) are considered vastly superior to your average Grandmasters player, even if you can generally find them in GM on the ladder.

From [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/GOMTV_Global_StarCraft_II_League):

> The GSL is an elaborate tournament which is separated into two tiers:
>
> - Code S contains the top tier players who are competing against each other to win the GSL.
> - Code A contains players who are competing against each other to enter Code S.

You will also hear them mention when someone is or was a Code S champion. This title is considered the biggest there is to win in the SC2 scene, and hence, the current and past champions are always big contenders at other events.

Comment: Oh ok, so this is related to the GSL :)  I had no idea, thanks a lot !

Comment: Don't worry, I know how it works ;)

Comment: There's also Code B which is the requirement to enter the Code A qualifying tournament. Code B players are any non-Koreans and Koreans above some arbitrary ladder cut off, usually high Masters.

Comment: I think you are missing a period or line break formatting. "Code S contains the top tier players who are competing against each other to win the GSL Code A" sounds weird...

Comment: @Alderath — I copied it verbatim from Liquipedia.

Comment: The lack of period does indeed harm readability. It looks like "code S players compete to win GSL code A" O_o Please put it in.

Comment: Edited for better punctuation.